# How to handle File Activation in Windows Store / WinJS apps

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm trying to make my text editor app handle a file launch. Microsoft has a sample of how to do this here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452684.aspx

Unfortunately, it stops at the point of receiving the file and doesn't give any info on how to actually open said file.

I can successfully handle the activated event, and I end up with an absolute path to the file. For example,

```
C:\Users\Rory\Documents\test.txt
```

Metro apps don't have permission to access absolute paths, except under certain conditions.

1. if the file is chosen by the user via a file picker
2. if the app has accessed the file before and the path has been stored in the Windows.Storage.AccessCache
3. **if the app is being passed the file as a launch.**

Even though number 3 applies in this case, I can't open the file.

I've tried `Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromPathAsync(path_to_file)` but I get this error

```
0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.

WinRT information: Cannot access the specified file or folder (඀6). 
The item is not in a location that the application has access to (including 
application data folders, folders that are accessible via capabilities 
and persisted items in the StorageApplicationPermissions lists). Verify 
that the file is not marked with system or hidden file attributes.
```

I've set my app package manifest to accept txt files already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StorageFile` or `StorageFile`s are passed to your app in the `WebUIFileActivatedEventArgs` argument. Try this:

```
app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.file) {
        if (args.detail.files.size > 0) {
            var storageFile = args.detail.files[0];
            Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(storageFile).then(function (text) {
                // Do something with the content of the file.
            });
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```